# Assigning Headers from one file to multiple data files

Tags: sas

I have a list of ~100 files. The first file contains header information for the other 98 data files. The information should be in table format, however each table is a different size (with regards to column and row number).

My goal is to import these files such that the column headers from the first file are correctly assigned.

Additional information:
I am told this list of files was generated using SAS (however I am not familiar with the file format) Furthermore, the "CIMPORT" command does not work on these files.

The files are "|" delineated

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Hi; welcome to the site.  The question you ask here is too general at the moment; we're not here to solve big problems, but smaller ones, or give advice on approaching bigger ones when more details are present.  In this case, it sounds like you need to provide more information - what kind of files are these, what does the header file look like, etc. - before you'll be able to get useful help.

Comment: It sounds like you have a metadata file that describes the other files.  You can use that to generate SAS code.  For a complete answer post some of the records from the first file and some of the data from the file that those records describe.

Comment: Show a sample of the 'first' file, or describe how it is layed out.  Show some examples of the other files including naming conventions. How do you associate the header information with a data file ?  Do the data files have a header row and the header information contain a 'dictionary' of all possible columns in the disparate data files?

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun issue. I came up with following way:

First lets load up some data.

```
proc import datafile = "\\Datadrive\mydata.csv"
    out=w_headers; 
    delimiter=";"; 
    guessingrows=32767;
run;

proc import datafile = "\\Datadrive\no_headers.csv"
    out=no_headers; 
    delimiter=";"; 
    guessingrows=32767;
run;
```

Then I extract the names of the columns and variable number to a dataset.

```
proc contents data=w_headers out=meta(keep=NAME VARNUM) noprint ; run ;
```

Then I create commands to renaming the columns without names to have proper names based on the existing. ones.

```
data meta;
    set meta;
    cmd = cats('VAR',VARNUM,'=', name);
run;
```

Here comes the kicker, I put the the commends to a variable. Next the variable is fed to `proc datasets` for renaming the columns.

```
proc sql noprint;
        select cmd into :cmd_list separated by ' ' from meta;
    quit;

proc datasets library = work nolist;
       modify no_headers;
       rename &cmd_list;
quit;
```

At this point my two datasets have identical column names. the method is a bit tricky, but works. I'm sure there is another way, but this was fun one. :)